# Can't resolve symbol FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_TO_ADJACENT

Tags: android, multi-window, split-screen

When I add the code below Android Studio shows it's not resolved, knowing that I'm targeting API 28

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_TO_ADJACENT);
```

I tried to use its integer value

```
intent.setFlags(4096);
```

It showed me another error that I must used one or more of predefined flags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo, it should be [Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_ADJACENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_ADJACENT), and available for API 24 and above.

Comment: You're welcome, usually when you get "Can't resolve symbol ...", chances are it's a spelling mistake, or a typo.